# Autolayout'd control's ACTUAL position at run time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Using XCode 6.0.1, iOS 8.

I have a UIButton I have placed via Autolayout/constraints.

I am trying to programmatically add buttons positioned relative to the first one.  Specifically, I am adding them in a circle around the center point of the initial button.  The math I am using to find the coordinates of the new buttons is working, except:

the autolayout'd button is reporting it's origin relative to the 536x536 superview interface builder is using, rather than the actual screen size of the device.

I know this because constraints say "Center X and Y in container" and it does appear in the middle of the screen, but no matter what device/screen size, frame.origin = (268, 268), which is the center of the view in IB (536 / 2 = 268).

So is there a way to somehow translate that to "actual device coordinates" as opposed to the original interface builder coordinates?

TIA

Edit:  I need to translate it no matter if it's centered or not.  I realize I can get the device's screen size and divide by 2 if it's centered.

Edit2:  @jrturton - where does it report its position at run-time?  What property?  Origin and center are both in correct.  Anyway, code:

Creating the buttons:

```
- (void)setupButtons: (int)buttonCount
{
if ((buttonCount > MAX_BUTTONS) || (buttonCount < MIN_BUTTONS)) {
    return;
}

float totalRads = degreesToRadians(360.0);
float deltaRads = totalRads / (float)buttonCount;
float radius = 30.0f;

NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CGRect centerFrame = self.centerMenuButton.frame;
for (int i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++) {

    CGPoint dest = CGPointMake(
                               (radius * cosf(i * deltaRads) + centerFrame.origin.x),
                               (radius * sinf(i * deltaRads) + centerFrame.origin.y)
                               );

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(dest.x, dest.y, 64.0, 64.0);
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pink_star"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttons addObject:button];
}

_menuButtons = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:buttons];
}
```

And displaying them:

```
- (void)showMenu
{
NSLog(@"showMenu");

for (int i = 0; i < [_menuButtons count]; i++) {
    UIButton *btn = [_menuButtons objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"origin: %f, %f", btn.frame.origin.x, btn.frame.origin.y);
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}

_menuOpen = YES;
}
```

I have some NSLogs for the center of the original, autolayout button (constraints were set in IB):

```
RadialMenuText[14125:6281339] x: 268.000000, y: 268.000000
```

And one for each button (2 currently):

```
RadialMenuText[14125:6281339] origin: 298.000000, 268.000000
RadialMenuText[14125:6281339] origin: 238.000000, 267.999997
```

Aside from the rounding error, the math looks semi-correct, in that the X coord is moving by the radius in the correct direction each time.  But again - the starting coordinates are incorrect because the autolayout'd button is reporting (268, 268).

Comment: Try using view debugging built into Xcode 6. When you do that, it will show you where the button is and also the run time constraints and position. Here is a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html) to an Apple doc that describes the basics of using it. –  David L

Comment: When are you doing the math, and how are you positioning the new buttons? Can we see some code?

Comment: A view positioned by auto layout will report its position at run time just like any other. Remember the centre property will be in the coordinate space of the buttons superview.

Comment: Works for me. Let's see some code.

Comment: Edit your post to include the code that creates the buttons and sets their constraints or positions or whatever.

Comment: @jrturton - being in the wrong coordinate space seems to be my problem.  So my question is - how do I convert to the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're calling `setupButtons:` from `viewDidLoad`.  That happens after the view controller has loaded its view from the storyboard, but before the system has resized the view (and its subviews) for the current device and orientation.

I suggest you fix this problem by using constraints to position your buttons instead of setting the frames.

You can't have a constraint between two views unless both views are in the same view hierarchy.  So add the buttons to the view hierarchy in `setupButtons:` but set them to hidden.  In `showMenu`, make them visible.

```
- (void)setupButtons:(int)buttonCount {
    if (buttonCount > MAX_BUTTONS |buttonCount < MIN_BUTTONS) {
        return;
    }

    float totalRads = degreesToRadians(360.0);
    float deltaRads = totalRads / (float)buttonCount;
    float radius = 30.0f;

    NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIView *centerView = self.centerMenuButton;
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++) {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pink_star"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:button];
        [buttons addObject:button];

        [button addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
            toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
            multiplier:0 constant:64]];
        [button addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
            toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
            multiplier:0 constant:64]];

        CGFloat radians = i * 2 * M_PI / buttonCount;
        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
            toItem:centerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
            multiplier:1 constant:radius * cos(radians)]];
        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
            toItem:centerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
            multiplier:1 constant:radius * sin(radians)]];
    }

    _menuButtons = [buttons copy];
}

- (void)showMenu {
    NSLog(@"showMenu");

    for (int i = 0; i < _menuButtons.count; i++) {
        UIButton *btn = _menuButtons[i];
        NSLog(@"origin: %f, %f", btn.frame.origin.x, btn.frame.origin.y);
        btn.hidden = NO;
    }

    _menuOpen = YES;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the thing, and works like a charm!  It also heads off another problem I was having using frame:  variable button sizes causing positioning to be offset by X amount.  

This is also some good knowledge on how to set constraints in code rather than in IB.  I am still trying to pick up Autolayout, and in IB I pretty much have it figured out - but I hadn't done anything like this before.  Thank you, sir.  You are both a gentleman and a scholar.  :)

Answer (score -1):

NSLayoutConstraints are processed after `layoutSubviews`. If you remove your NSLayoutConstraints from your auto layout view and replace with `UIViewAutoresizingFlexible*` constants, the frame of your button will be updated when you call `[super layoutSubviews]` within your `layoutSubviews` override.

@jrturton also makes a good point above regarding your calculation of the center. If your complaint is that the center that's being reported is the center within its superview, that is expected behaviour. If you want the center relative to the screen, you will need to convert it using `[[UIScreen mainScreen] convertPoint:point fromView:theView]`.

Comment: The constraint solver runs before `layoutSubviews`.  `-[UIView layoutSubviews]` applies the solution to `self`'s subviews.  This is why you need to call `[super layoutSubviews]` if you override `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: In my experience, view constraints will apply after `layoutSubviews` returns.